# Можно ли в typescript создать переменную определённого типа динамически, имея параметр строчного типа?

Tags: typescript

Можно ли в typescript создать переменную определённого типа динамически, имея параметр строчного типа?
Я имею ввиду, если функции передаёшь "number", "dog" или "user" а она создаёт переменную, подтянув этот тип?

Если создать кортеж.
например `store['book'] = new Book()` и так далее. Или так не делают и это больше говнокод?

а функция типа add('book').
Ну я фактически вижу через switch case.

Comment: сомневаюсь что что-то такое может быть, так как `ts` это не просто язык строгой типизации, но еще и статической — он обязан транспилироваться в `js`, а в данном случае требуется именно динамическая типизация, конечно ни кто не мешает сделать что-то типа `if else` но вероятно это не то что требуется в вопросе.

Comment: что значит "создает переменную"?

Comment: @Grundy имел ввиду создать кортеж с элементами разного типа как хранилище.
например store['book'] = new Book() и так далее. Или так не делают и это больше говнокод?

Comment: Ваш пример это не кортеж, так только сильнее запутываете

Comment: почему именно строки нужны?